Embedding inline images in emails broken when upgrading from Laravel 9 to 11
I noticed  after updating from Laravel 9 to 11 that embedded email images stopped showing and the code below started returning the attachment filenames like JipwOYRW4e instead of the Content-ID like f150f0a9b59076bc9768a5910cce5d7b@symfony
$message->embed(resource_path('assets/images/email/myimg.png'))

If I override Illuminate/Mail/Message::embed() to return the Content ID instead like below the images end up being displayed like before again:
$cid = Str::random(10);
$dataPart = (new DataPart(new File($file), $cid))->asInline();
$this->message->addPart(
    $dataPart
);

return "cid:" . $dataPart->getContentId();

Obviously I'd rather not override framework classes though so what's a better way of fixing this?

Have you tried php artisan storage:link --force and php artisan optimize:clear? They may not be the solution but after upgrading my version of Laravel, these are some of the first things I would do.

Yeah I already cleared all the cached stuff.
To be clear, the correct files are being included in the emails, it's just the <img src=cid: parts in the body where it's not referencing the right cid attachment.
I don't think storage:link would help with that unless I decide to link to the images externally rather than embedding
